# How to prevent user from viewing the content of a folder on fedora 14?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-14

assuming there is only one user account on the OS, it does not belong to the root group
is there any command line which i could enter at the terminal (by su to become root) to restrict viewing of the folder contents? (not deny read write by the system).
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The read permission is required to get a directory listing. If the user is not in the owning group of the directory…

```
chmod o-r /path/to/directory
```

otherwise,

```
chmod go-r /path/to/directory
```

That said, the user can still go into the directory, and potentially open further files or directories therein. You must remove the executable permission on the directory to disallow this.

```
chmod o-x /path/to/directory
```

or

```
chmod go-x /path/to/directory
```

Be careful when removing the owning group's permissions, as some of them are required for some daemons to properly function. You should just remove the user from the group instead.